# Python/Openshift application using NLTK resources

Tags: nltk, openshift

I hosted a Python webservice application in openshift which uses RSLP Stemmer module of nltk, but the log of service reported that:

```
[...] Resource 'stemmers/rslp/step0.pt' not found. Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource: >>> nltk.download()

Searched in:
 - '/var/lib/openshift/539a61ab5973caa2410000bf/nltk_data'
 - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
 - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
 - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
 - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'  [...]
```

I concluded that the module is not installed properly. Someone knows how install resources of nltk in OpenShift/Python application??

PS: portuguese stopwords module also contains an error like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NLTK package on OpenShift. The reason it is not working for you is because NLTK package by default expect corpus in user home directory. In OpenShift, you cannot write to user home but have to use $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR for storing data. To solve this problem do the follwing:

1. Create an environment variable called NLTK_DATA with value $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR. After creating environment variable restart the app using rhc app-restart command.
2. SSH into your application gear using rhc ssh command
3. Activate the virtual environment and download the corpus using the commads shown below.

   . $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate
   curl https://raw.github.com/sloria/TextBlob/master/download_corpora.py | python

I have written a blog on Textblob package that underneath uses NLTK package https://www.openshift.com/blogs/day-9-textblob-finding-sentiments-in-text